# Why can't React's forwardRef work well with Material UI's styled?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

When using `forwardRef` with `styled`, I see this odd error : "React Hook ... cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function."

For example:

```
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { useTranslation } from '../lib/i18n';

const FooComponent = styled(({ className }) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  return <div className={ className }>{ t('This is fine') }</div>;
})(() => ({
  // CSS styles...
});
```

```
import { forwardRef } from 'react';
import { useTranslation } from '../lib/i18n';

const FooComponent = forwardRef(((), ref) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  return <div ref={ref}>{ t('This is fine, too!') }</div>;
});
```

```
import { forwardRef } from 'react';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { useTranslation } from '../lib/i18n';

const FooComponent = forwardRef( styled(({ className }, ref) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();    // ERROR here!
  return <div ref={ref} className={ className }>{ t('This is NOT fine') }</div>; 
})(() => ({
  // CSS styles...
})));
```

Why is there an error in the 3rd component? Is the only solution to have a custom `ref` prop?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main issue with your code is that `styled()` doesn't expect a second `ref` parameter, and doesn't know what to do with it. In contrast, `forwardRef()` does expect you to provide a function with a second `ref` parameter.

So to solve your problem the way you apply `forwardRef()` and `styled()` should be swapped (note that parentheses also slightly change).

```
const FooComponent = styled( forwardRef(({ className }, ref) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  return <div ref={ref} className={ className }>{ t('This is NOT fine') }</div>; 
}))(() => ({
  // CSS styles...
}));

// or maybe easier to understand

const UnstyledFooComponent = forwardRef(({ className }, ref) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  return <div ref={ref} className={ className }>{ t('This is NOT fine') }</div>; 
});

const styling = (() => ({
  // CSS styles...
});

const FooComponent = styled(UnstyledFooComponent)(styling);
```

This will pass the the `(props, ref) => ...` callback to `forwardRef()`, which understands the second `ref` parameter.

We'll then pass the resulting component to `styled()`.

It's then up to `styled()` to pass the `ref`, from the trickery that `styled()` does, down to your component. Luckily `styled()` keeps this into account and creates a styled component that forwards the ref down.

If `styled()` didn't forward the ref down things would get a lot more complicated.

```js
const { useRef, useEffect, forwardRef } = React;
const { styled } = MaterialUI;

const FooComponent = styled(forwardRef(({ className }, ref) => {
  const { t } = I18n.useTranslation();
  return <div ref={ref} className={ className }>{ t('This is fine') }</div>;
}))(() => ({
  backgroundColor: "red"
}));

function App() {
  const fooRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(fooRef.current);
  }, []);
  
  return <FooComponent className="foo" ref={fooRef} />;
}

// mock `useTranslation()`
const I18n = React.createContext();
I18n.useTranslation = function () {
  const translations = React.useContext(I18n);

  const t = React.useCallback((text) => {
    if (!(text in translations))
      throw new Error(`no translation found for "${text}"`);

    return translations[text];
  }, [translations]);
      
  return { t, translations };
};

const translations = {
  nl: {
    "This is fine": "Dit is oké",
  }
};

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(document.querySelector("#root"))
  .render(
    <React.StrictMode>
      <I18n.Provider value={translations.nl}>
        <App />
      </I18n.Provider>
    </React.StrictMode>
  );
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" />
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/@mui/material@5/umd/material-ui.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I had the idea, but I stubbornly expected that `styled` would not pass the second argument `ref`.

Comment: You are like Tony Stark, but also you know React. Thanks, you saved me a lot of time.